# Pushing checkbox values from one array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I have very little experience with JavaScript however I am attempting to write a function which pushes checkbox values from one array to another. I have written the following code, however it doesn't appear to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
var pages = document.forms['frm_list'].elements[ 'pages[]' ];
var selected = document.forms['frm_list'].elements[ 'selectedPages[]' ];
console.log(pages);
console.log(selected);


// using reference to sports obtained above
    for (var i=0, len=pages.length; i<len; i++) {
        pages[i].onclick = addPage;
    }

function addPage() {
    if ( this.checked ) {
        console.log(this);
        selected.push(pages);
        alert( this.value );
    } else {
        alert( this.value );
    }
}
```

Comment: `pages, selected` are not `Arrays` so, you can't use `.push()` on it.

Comment: What could I use as an alternative?

Comment: Declare any variable to an array then push in it.

Comment: Like var pages = [document.forms['frm_list'].elements[ 'pages[]' ]]; ?